# Fabric's get command failing

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I have a script which will go through all of the directories on a list of servers, and grab all of the subfolders of a specific folder, however one of the folders is presenting with an error 'permission denied'. Thats ok, because I dont need that folder, but once I get that error, the get() fails and the script does not collect the rest of the folders.

So far I've tried:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    get('/path/to/logs',local_folder)
```

And I've tried:

```
try:
    get('/path/to/logs', local_folder)
except:
    pass
```

I still run into the 'permission denied' error and it still will not collect the rest of the logs.

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check file/folder permissions?

Comment: Yes, the folder/file perms are specifically not readable. And thats fine. I just need to know how to get the get() operation to move past the error.

Comment: Have you tried: from fabric.api import warn_only; with warn_only(): get('/path/to/logs', local_folder)

Comment: I've tried that. I still hit Permission Denied and the script stops grabbing other folders.